# JSP Page not Redirect to Servlet Page After Servlet is Executed

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, datepicker

i have strange problem. I have a page using datepicker from https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker in my JSP page. The datepicker will executed a servlet page called **getKodeTrsInv** using this syntax:

```
 function(start, end) {
      console.log("Callback has been called!");
       $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
       var start = start.format('YYYY-MM-D');
       var end = end.format('YYYY-MM-D');
       getTransaction(start, end);
 }
```

The function **getTransaction**:

```
  function getTransaction(start,end){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<%= request.getContextPath() %>/getKodeTrsInv",
            data:{
                startdate:start,
                enddate:end
            },
            success:function(msg){
                //alert("Data Inserted" + msg); 
            },
            error:function(msg){
                alert("Data Failed to save" + msg); 
            }
        });
    }
```

The servlet is executed to show result from a controller called MasterPesanan using function **functionGetTransactionTime(startdate,enddate);**

This is the servlet page:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    System sys = new System();

    try {
        /* GET PARAMETER INPUTS */
        Date sd = sys.convertStringToDate(request.getParameter("startdate"));
        Date ed = sys.convertStringToDate(request.getParameter("enddate"));
        /* CONVERT TO DATE SQL TO EXECUTED*/
        java.sql.Date startdate = new java.sql.Date(sd.getTime());
        java.sql.Date enddate = new java.sql.Date(ed.getTime());

        /*EXECUTE THE CURRENT DATA*/
        MasterPesanan psn = new MasterPesanan();
        List<Pesanan> pesanan = psn.functionGetTransactionTime(startdate,enddate);
        if(pesanan != null){
            request.setAttribute("kodeTransaksi", pesanan);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("system/invoice.jsp").forward(request,response);
       } else {
           java.lang.System.out.println("Get Kode Transaction For Inovice Error");
       }
    } catch(ParseException pe){
        java.lang.System.out.println("Get Kode Transaction For Invoice error : " + pe.getCause());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        java.lang.System.out.println("Error Exception " + e);
    }

    finally {            
        java.lang.System.out.println("Get Kode Transaction For Invoice has been executed");
    } 
}
```

The problem is, when the servlet is executed, the servlet works, but the PAGE is not redirect. I have check the FIREBUG, the servlet is redirected there, but in my browser it's stucked.

For more information, the result list from function **functionGetTransactionTime(startdate,enddate);** is shown in firebug.
Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect will only redirect the page when you actually navigate to the servlet.  If the servlet is called via Ajax, the response returned to Ajax will be the response from the page redirected to in the servlet, but the page the user sees will not redirect.  Only the text returned to Ajax will be from the page that the servlet redirected to. In other words, the redirect happens only in the background. The user will still see the same page. If you want a real redirect, where the page the user sees changes, then don't use Ajax to call the servlet: i.e. Send the user to the servlet with an HTML form (or a regular link).

Comment: so, if the returned variable from the ajax is whole jsp page, how do i just find specific object to be consume? example the object is array list.

Comment: You can format the output as just plain text where the list is separated by a certain character (e.g. an asterick), and then in javascript use var array = output.split("*"); to turn it into an array.

Comment: finally i found the solution using out.print method.